# not able to configure aws x-ray using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-xray, rexray

i'm using the third party library from https://github.com/patrickkerrigan/php-xray since aws do not have any x-ray sdk for php

this is how i trace my application using the library

however, i'm not able to see any traceses is made the trace view map

```
Trace::getInstance() 
    ->setName('my-app')
    ->setUrl('http://example.com') 
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->begin();

echo 'my function'; 

Trace::getInstance()
    ->end() 
    ->setResponseCode(http_response_code())
    ->setError(http_response_code() >= 400 && http_response_code() < 500)
    ->setFault(http_response_code() >= 500)
    ->submit(new \Pkerrigan\Xray\Submission\DaemonSegmentSubmitter());
```

Comment: What was the point in showing the code twice?

Comment: wrongly creating the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

AWS X-Ray does not vend an SDK for PHP, but we do vend the [AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry in PHP](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/php-sdk/trace-manual-instr). You can use OpenTelemetry PHP to instrument libraries that are supported in OpenTelemetry PHP (including [AWS SDK](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-php-contrib/blob/main/src/Aws/README-AwsSdkInstrumentation.md)) and/or manually create spans as necessary and export traces to AWS X-Ray.

The [ADOT documentation contains detailed instructions on getting started and setting up all the components to send trace data to the AWS X-Ray backend](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/php-sdk/trace-manual-instr#installation). We also provide a [sample app](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-php/tree/main) that can be used to get started with using ADOT PHP.